# How can I combine a form with onclick button to perform function with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, function

I'm trying to build a simple landing page with a javascript function that converts a woman's US shoe size to EU shoe size and all through a form. I'd like to allow the user to input their US shoe size in the form and click on a  element to display their EU shoe size directly on the page. I'm really struggling here, can someone help me organize this?! Maybe it's my placements...do I combine my button onclick in my form id?
What I really need is it written out for me ╮(╯_╰)╭

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="side">
    <h2>What's Your Shoe Size?</h2>
    <h5>Don't know your shoe size? No problem!</h5>
    <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>

<p>Enter your US shoe size, then click "Submit" to submit the form:</p>
<form id="shoeSize" action="/action_page.php">
 US shoe size: <input type="number" name="size">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button onclick="findEuroSizeByUsSize('shoeSizeMap')">Try it</button>
<p id="shoeSizeMap"></p>
<p>Enter your US shoe size, then click "Submit" to submit the form:</p>

<button onclick="findEuroSizeByUsSize('shoeSizeMap')">Try it</button>

<p id="shoeSizeMap"></p>
```

Function:

```
function findEuroSizeByUsSize(usSize) {
 var result = shoeSizeMap.find(function(shoeSize) { 
 return shoeSize.usSize == euroSize; 
 }); 
 return result ? result.euroSize : 'unknown size'; 
 } 
 
 findEuroSizeByUsSize('5'); // returns 35
```

Array:

```
var shoeSizeMap = [ 
{ 'usSize: 5', euroSize: '35' }, 
{ 'usSize: 6', euroSize: '36' }, 
{ 'usSize: 7', euroSize: '37' }, 
{ 'usSize: 8', euroSize: '38' }, 
{ 'usSize: 9', euroSize: '39' }, 
{ 'usSize: 10', euroSize: '40' }, 
{ 'usSize: 11', euroSize: '41' }, 
{ 'usSize: 12', euroSize: '42' ];
</script>
```

Updates as of 4/30:

```
<div class="row"> <div class="side"> 
<h2>What's Your Shoe Size?</h2> 
<h5>Don't know your shoe size? No problem!</h5> 
<div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
```

```
<p>Enter your US shoe size, then click "Try it" to submit the form:</p> 
<form id="usShoeSize"> <input type="number" name="size">
<button onclick=">Try it</button> <p id="usShoeSize"></p>
```

Function:

```
function findEuroSizeByUsSize(id="usShoeSize") { 
var usSize = document.getElementById("usShoeSize").value;
var result = shoeSizeMap.find(function(shoeSize) { 
return shoeSize.usSize == euroSize; }); 

return result ? result.euroSize : 'unknown size'; } 

findEuroSizeByUsSize(id="usShoeSize").value; // returns 35
```

Array:

```
<script>
var shoeSizeMap = [ 
{ usSize: “5”, euroSize: “35” }, 
{ usSize: “6”, euroSize: “36” }, 
{ usSize: “7”, euroSize: “37” }, 
{ usSize: “8”, euroSize: “38” }, 
{ usSize: “9”, euroSize: “39” }, 
{ usSize: “10”, euroSize: “40” }, 
{ usSize: “11”, euroSize: “41” }, 
{ usSize: “12”, euroSize: “42” }];
</script>
```

Comment: You have to write the property usSize without quotations marks {usSize: '5', euroSize: '35' }

Comment: `findEuroSizeByUsSize('shoeSizeMap')` will pass the string `'shoeSizeMap'` as a parameter to the function. Remove that. Instead, add an `id="usShoeSize"` to US shoe size input element. Inside the function, add `var usSize = document.getElementById("usShoeSize").value` to get the input's value. Use that in the `find`

Comment: Also, `shoeSizeMap` is missing several quotes and a `}` for the last object

Comment: @adiga I made changes labeled as "Updates as of 4/30:"

Comment: You need to add an `id` to the `input` and you need to use the same `id` in `getElementById`. Not the form's id.' You don't need to pass any parameter `id="usShoeSize"` to the function